# MS Word document not visible when opening programmatically through interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

The following code opens the document in the background but not make it visible even though I am using Visible = true and oDoc.Activate();

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
Word.Application oApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Folder1\Test1.docx", Visible: true);
oDoc.Activate();
```

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964557/how-can-i-make-word-visible-when-opening-a-document-through-interop), it should have worked.

Comment: try this it should work. `oApp.Application.Visible = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to set the [Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839544(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Application class.

See [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.